# Unable to access variable declared inside function from if body

Tags: javascript, typescript, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to access a variable, which I declared at the top of the function from inside of an if statement (also in that same function).
This is the code I wrote:

```
function getAround(x: number, y: number): number {
  console.log({x, y});
  let around: number = 0;
  const max = (props.size - 1);
  console.log({around});
  // top
  if (y > 0 && grid[y - 1][x].bomb) {
    console.log({max: this.max});
    around++;
  }
  // top right
  if (y < 0 && x > max && grid[y - 1][x + 1].bomb) {
    around++;
  }

  //right
  if (x < max && grid[y][x + 1]) {
    around++;
  }

  //bottom right
  if (y < max && x < max && grid[y + 1][x + 1]) {
    around++;
  }

  //bottom
  if (y < max && grid[y + 1][x]) {
    around++;
  }

  //left bottom
  if (y < max && x > 0 && grid[y + 1][x - 1]) {
    around++;
  }

  //left
  if (x > 0 && grid[y][x - 1]) {
    around++;
  }

  //top left
  if (y > 0 && x > 0 && grid[y - 1][x - 1]) {
    around++;
  }
  return around;
}
```

For some reason, it fails when trying to increase around, so I tried creating a simpler version:

```
function simple(x: number, y: number): number {
  let around: number = 0;
  if (x > y) {
    around++;
  }
  return around;
}
```

The simple version works for some reason. From my understanding, both of these should work fine though, right?
Here is the error I get:

```
Error while mounting app: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')
    at getAround (PlayingField.vue:89)
    at PlayingField.vue:50
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at PlayingField.vue:50
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at getAllAround (PlayingField.vue:49)
    at generateGrid (PlayingField.vue:41)
    at setup (PlayingField.vue:45)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6708)
    at setupStatefulComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6317)
```

Line 89 contains the following code:

```
console.log({max: this.max});
```

I'm unsure if this is important, but I am using Nuxt 3 and the code is inside a `script setup` tag.

Comment: You've misunderstood the error message, `grid[n]` is not defined when you're trying to read `grid[n][1]`.

Comment: Also, in the future if you supply an error message, tell us what line triggered it, or in this case, you could have given us the link to the Playground code.

Comment: @Teemu I don't quite understand. The error states line 89 in PlayingField.vue. That line is this: `console.log({max: this.max});`.

Comment: I doubt the locationing is a bit off. Maybe it's the line above, where you have `grid[y - 1][x]`. Check what `y-1` is just before the `if`, and does `grid[y - 1]` actually exist when `x == 1`.

Comment: Yeah. Seems like it was off by one line. Fixed the problem and now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The line mentioned in the error is off by one and the error actually was in line  88. After fixing my if statement it now works flawlessly.

For future reference: The browser used was Edge (Chromium) version 96.0.1054.41 on Windows 10.